# Agency offering unknown ir35 status

Tags: united-kingdom, contractors

I have an agency looking to offer an unknown IR35 (Incoming UK tax law) status, and then come April, potentially offering a new contract if it's deemed inside [IR35].

Is this an absolute minefield waiting to happen?

Comment: "inside" inside what?

Comment: @SolarMike, OP is referring to incoming IR35 (the name of the tax law) amendments due in the UK in April. The change is that the End Client (hiring company) must make a Determination of Tax Status, which indicates whether a contract worker is in business on their own account ("outside" the rules), or deemed to be an employee of the hiring company ("inside" the rules).

Comment: Thanks chaps - updated to reflect not everyone is in the UK, and knows what "inside" would mean.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because it's already too late. The key legal dates are based on payments, not contract dates. If you're working a month, then invoicing on 30 day terms, your payments for work done today could easily fall within the scope of the new rules.

Answer (score 3):

As @Dan says, for payment reasons it's too late.

Either decline, or accept on the basis that it's "inside" and ask your accountant to generate the paperwork (or work through a payroll/umbrella).

Another huge risk is if the subsequent, post-April contract is deemed "inside", but is not significantly different from the pre-April one, HMRC will argue during an investigation that you should have been "inside" all along. This will prompt them to widen the investigation back in time through your other contracts.